# MS SQL Server extensions won't load in PHP 5.6.5, Apache 2.4 on Windows 10.1

Tags: php, sql-server

I've followed all the instructions and troubleshooting I could find, but I cannot get the extensions for SQL Server to load in PHP. I'm running SQL Server Express 2012.

I've tried the official MS drivers for 5.6 as well as the unofficial drivers, both x32 and x64.

I have the drivers in the ext directory, and just to be sure I also copied them to the php directory.

I have SQL Server Native Client installed. I've restarted Apache each time I've copied new dlls. And just for the heck of it I also tried the drivers for 55 and 54 in all the different versions.

Nothing works. The Apache logs include nothing relevant. Each time I get this error message on my page:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

If anyone has any any ideas what else I can try, I'd be very grateful

Comment: There are few `php.ini` files one for Apache and one for PHP, this dll's must be included in both. Is this done? Are dll's proper version (are supported) and thread safe/non thread safe? What about PHP `error.log`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can't find another php.ini file anywhere in the Apache24 directory. I've tried every dll I could find, both MS and unsupported x32 and x64. I've also tried 53, 54, 55 and 56. My installation is on Windows, so it's ts, and those are the ones I've tried.

Comment: Look at phpinfo(), there must be a pass of php.ini that is used.

Comment: @gofr  phpinfo() lists the following:                                             Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\WINDOWS                         Loaded Configuration File  C:\PHP\php.ini

Comment: php.ini in c:\windows\? Strange. Can you, please, check if there is a php.ini in c:\windows? Try change it with one from c:\php\php.ini if it has proper configuration.

Comment: As workaround, I can suggest you to install xamp, it has all configuration you need 'on' by default.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who pitched in to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who pitched in to help me solve this problem, especially gofr1, who never gives up. My situation is that I'm running Apache 2.4 x64 on Windows 10.1 x64. But I didn't realize that I had installed PHP x32. When I switched to PHP x64 and loaded the unofficial x64 sqlsrv drivers it all started working and both sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv show up in phpinfo(). By the way, there was no php.ini in c:\Windows, so I have no idea what was going on there. But finally it's working.

Comment: Great, you solve this! :)